# Traveling from Phoenix, AZ to Mexicali to Guadalajara

Tags: passports, paperwork, international-travel, us-citizens, mexico

My bf and I are traveling for a wedding in Oct. We planned on driving from phoenix to mexicali and flying from there to Guadalajara.

My questions are: can we use our drivers license to get into Mexicali or should we get the passport card? Trying to avoid getting the book it is expensive for us.

Also, once in Mexicali, do we NEED the passport card to fly to Guadalajara or can we just use our ID and the tourist card? We will be there about 4 days.

Comment: (1) Do you have an [enhanced driver's license?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Drivers_License) (2) Do you want to be able to return to the US later?

Comment: I updated the tags.  I am assuming from context that both of you are US citizens, but please correct me if this is wrong.  Also, TSA is only responsible for airport security at US airports; they have nothing to do with land border crossings or flights within Mexico.  So I removed that tag.

Comment: I do not. I live in Arizona so we were not required to have EDL's yet. Our regular license is valid for travel by air until 2020 but we can apply for voluntary traveler ID's. And yes we will return to the US after 4 days. We both have our birth certificates if required.